# Compile Error on Java 7 Diamond Operator: ArrayList<>();

Tags: java, eclipse, diamond-operator

I have this line of code:

```
List<IObserver<?>> observers = new ArrayList<>();
```

and get the 3 following Errors:

```
Cannot instantiate the type ArrayList<?>
Syntax error on token "<", ? expected after this token
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<?> to List<IObserver<?>>
```

I am using Eclipse 3.7, I installed JDK 7 update 5 and the Project is set to use the JRE System Library[JavaSE1.7] in the Build Path.

Passing in the `IObserver<?>` on the right side compiles fine, but I have to use the diamond operator.

I think this is a configuration problem, but I can't figure out what I have missed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code should work  : diamond operator is used correctly.
I suggest you to install a more recent version of Eclipse (Indigo or Juno), and set the compiler compliance level to 1.7.

Here is a simple working example (IObserver is invented here). Print to the console : "we are 2"

```
package it.ant.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<IObserver<?>> observers = new ArrayList<>();
        IObserver<String> stringObserver = new Observer<>();
        IObserver<Integer> integerObserver = new Observer<>();
        stringObserver.addObserved("we are ");
        integerObserver.addObserved(2);

        observers.add(stringObserver);
        observers.add(integerObserver);

        for (IObserver<?> o : observers) {
            System.out.print(o.getObserved());
        }

    }
}

interface IObserver<T> {    
    void addObserved(T t);
    T getObserved();
}

class Observer<T> implements IObserver<T> { 
    private T observed;

    @Override
    public void addObserved(T observed) {
        this.observed = observed;

    }

    @Override
    public T getObserved() {
        return observed;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right. Eclipse 3.7.0 does not support a Java 7 compiler. I moved to Eclise 4.2

Comment: In fact Eclipse 3.7 supports the Java 7 compiler(I would wonder if it does not), but some problems with the setup. So I stay with 4.2 Juno

Answer (score 3):

Diamond operator will work only when you don't have `wildcard` as your generic type in you LHS..

```
List<IObserver<?>> observers = new ArrayList<>();
```

In this code, Compiler sees the LHS, and is satisfied that it can be `List` of `IObserver` of `anytype`..

But, at runtime, you need to have the actual type for this `anytype`..

Had you not used the `Wildcard` on LHS, it would have worked..  Actually your above code is equivalent to (If we see it as prior to Java 7): -

```
List<IObserver<?>> observers = new ArrayList<IObserver<?>>();
```

As RHS generic type is inferred from the LHS..Now you see the problem?? You don't have a `Concrete Type` to make `object` of `IObserver` on RHS..

Comment: @Simulant.. Well might work.. I just read this thing somewhere.. So, I just know it theoretically.. May be I'm wrong. (But, as far as I know, We need to have `Concrete` generic type on RHS).. Based on this information, I though this would be a problem..